# Is there any way to increase the display time of the HTML required validation message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Since the HTML required validation message is appearing for a small period of time, Is there any solution to increase the appear time of the HTML required validation message?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: This is browser validation message, you need to write custom validation message to meet your needs..

Comment: If it helps, you can show that a field contains invalid input simply with css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid _This does require the field to have special types (like email) or a pattern-attribute._

Comment: Also this might help too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Thanks, But I need to display a validation message which appears permanently or for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a *user agent* (browser) feature, you have no control over it short of hacky solutions like triggering submit repeatedly. You can only override (replace) the behavior. Also, you'll see different behavior with different browsers.

Since you've tagged jQuery, I'd suggest looking into [jQuery's validate plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). It'll give you full, flexible control over your user experience.